# LinkedList Output Limit Exceeding

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

**can anyone help me why I'm getting the output limit exceeded in my code?**

This is the problem link
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rearrange-a-linked-list/1

I'm getting an error on the input below:
7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Problem Statement:
Given a singly linked list, the task is to rearrange it in a way that all odd position nodes are together and all even positions node are together.
Assume the first element to be at position 1 followed by second element at position 2 and so on.
Note: You should place all odd positioned nodes first and then the even positioned ones. (considering 1 based indexing). Also, the relative order of odd positioned nodes and even positioned nodes should be maintained.

Example 1:

Input:
LinkedList: 1->2->3->4
Output: 1 3 2 4
Explanation:
Odd elements are 1, 3 and even elements are
2, 4. Hence, resultant linked list is
1->3->2->4.
Example 2:

Input:
LinkedList: 1->2->3->4->5
Output: 1 3 5 2 4
Explanation:
Odd elements are 1, 3, 5 and even elements are
2, 4. Hence, resultant linked list is
1->3->5->2->4.
Your Task:
The task is to complete the function rearrangeEvenOdd() which rearranges the nodes in the linked list as required and doesn't return anything.

Expected Time Complexity: O(N).
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1).

Constraints:
1 ≤ Size of the linked list ≤ 10^4
0 ≤ value of linked list ≤ 10^3

```
//{ Driver Code Starts
// C program to find nth Node in linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/* Link list Node */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    
    Node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};



// } Driver Code Ends
// Node structure

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    
    Node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};


class Solution
{
    public:
    void rearrangeEvenOdd(Node *head)
    {
       // Your Code here
       if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL || head->next->next==NULL){
           return;
       }
       Node* temp = head;
       Node* oddSt = temp;
       Node* oddEnd = temp;
       temp = temp->next;
       Node* evenSt = temp;
       Node* evenEnd = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
         int n = 1;
        
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if(n%2!=0){
            oddEnd->next = temp;
            oddEnd = oddEnd->next;
           }
           else{
            evenEnd->next = temp; 
            evenEnd = evenEnd->next;
           }
          temp = temp->next; 
          n++;
       }
       
          oddEnd->next = evenSt;
    }
    
   
};


//{ Driver Code Starts.

/* Driver program to test above function*/
int main()
{
    int T,i,n,l;

    cin>>T;

    while(T--)
    {
        struct Node *head = NULL;
        struct Node *temp = head;
        cin>>n;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            cin>>l;

            if (head == NULL)
            {   
                head = temp = new Node(l); 
                
            }
            else
            {  temp->next = new Node(l);
               temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        Solution ob;
        ob.rearrangeEvenOdd(head);
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

// } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't really answerable unless you include the details of the testing framework and the input on which the code fails. You also need to include a complete program that we can test ourselves without going to the linked website. i.e., you need to include an [mcve].

Comment: You probably have to debug your code yourself. And I mean actively debug by stepping 1 line at a time looking at your variables and flow after each line is executed.

Comment: Hint: where evenEnd->next points to after the loop is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't need a working code, but just a hint on how to solve the problem.

1. If the list has 2 or fewer elements, return (done)
2. Create and initialize a counter (done)
3. Create a head for the list of the "even" elements and initialize it to `nullptr` (this is C++) to make the list empty
4. Traverse the input list to its end. While doing so:

   - update the counter by +1
   - move each input list element for which the counter is even to the end of the "even" list
5. Merge the two lists in the required order

Notice that step 4 is a small variation on the problem of removing every second list item. The only difference is that you don't remove it (e.g. by using `delete` operator), but move it (push back) to the other list.

One thing that helps a lot in dealing with linked lists is to draw a sketch of a simple list, with all the pointers, and how you will manage it step by step.

A correct answer consists of pointer operations only, do not move the data.

Hope it helps.

### EDIT

Here's the situation for a 3-element list before the loop:

[image]

This is the situation after the loop:
[image]

The odd list is OK, but the even list is broken.

If you now do

```
oddEnd->next = evenSt;
```

you get a circular list that never ends:

[image]

Interestingly, your solution seems to be correct for  lists with even number of elements.

Comment: I know that approach uses two different pointers odd and even but I want to know what's the issue in that approach, and why I'm getting the output limit exceeded. please help me that my humble request.